# How to align bootstrap text and button horizontally

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am coding with react and bootstrap. laid out button and text like below.

```
  <div>
    <h3> <strong>"Title"</strong> </h3>
    <Button color="primary" className="mr-xs">
      <i className="fa fa-check mr-xs mb-xs" />Edit
    </Button>
  </div>
```

[image]

but I want to align text and button horizontally like below.
want to reserve some space between text and button

Any easy way to do this using bootstrap class name or css?

[image]

Comment: did you try to use `row` and `col` to do what you want?

Comment: I just wondered any other simple way to do this. I know row and col.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by doing-

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-6">
        <h3><strong>"Title"</strong> </h3>
    </div>
    <div className="col-6">
        <Button color="primary" className="mr-xs">
         <i className="fa fa-check mr-xs mb-xs" />Edit
        </Button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using only Bootstrap

Make your div a flex display and then use margins to get appropriate result or `justify-content-start`, `justify-content-end`, `justify-content-center`, etc.

```
<div className="d-flex flex-row">
    <div >
        <h3><strong>"Title"</strong> </h3>
        <Button color="primary" className="mr-xs">
         <i className="fa fa-check mr-xs mb-xs" />Edit
        </Button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can look at Bootstrap's documentation for more detail on ".d-flex" [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in a `<div class='row'></div>`